# Mails from Teamroom have http links instead of https

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino, agents

When setting up a teamroom, The 8.5.3 from the extlib from openntf, one of the config items is for the URL.

So when sending reminders and so on from the teamroom it will have a notes doclink and a weblink.

In our test/dev environment it worked like a charm.
The users where baffled when they worked with the webclient. (xpages)

After upgrading one of our teamrooms in the prod env. We got calls that the links in the emails did not work.

The generated links where http instead of https. I mean the links in the emails created for reviewers or reminders a item is overdue.

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our internal domino production environment we only use https. 
But in our test/development env we can only use http at the moment.

Opening the template in the designer and looking at the agents i discovered:

for server

```
wMail = "  http://" + serverName +"/"+ dbpath +"/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId="+doc.universalid
```

for local:

```
wMail = "  http://"+ getWebAddress +"/"+ dbpath+"/$All/"+doc.universalid
```

So http protocol is hardcoded.

Code strings are found in these agents.

- Send Newsletters
- SendReminder
- (wSendLink)

A quick fix was to replace http for https.

A better solution is to add a checkbox to the teamroomsetup form, advanced options tab.
And change the code in the agents to get the value depending on value generate a http or https url.

I did not have the time for this yet. But it is not so difficult to do.

To consider:
Whatever you do change it in the template not in the teamroom nsf.
Would be a shame to find out the next day that you're changes where overwritten with the templates default.

Hope it saves time

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the properties of the database to force it to be opened using HTTPS?

Comment: Is that via 'Database Properties'-'Basic'-'Require SSL Connection'?

Comment: I think bruce means that setting. But this will only force https if you open a page in http so it would not change the agents code

Comment: Bruce i prepared a second teamroom en did set it to require ssl connections, no code change so teamroom is standard. Generated review mails got the email link is http. clicked it and got a page cannot be found well an error page. This can be due to how we configured the server, we only allow https, so http will be ignored. In our case its still the best to change the code. Maybe i should have leaved the protocol http:// out. But that would mean changing the code.

Comment: You could also change the Internet Site security settings to "Redirect TCP to SSL"

Comment: In our network we have a load balancer so "Redirect TCP to SSL" setting has no positive affect. Alas.